# PHP multiple String Replace

Tags: php, str-replace

I'm trying to replace some words in my string for a white space, but the words that I try to replace are different all the time, except for the first 3 characters. 
For example I have this string:

```
"Hello, my name is Lorum and toc341013697 I'm 29 years old. And I toc241053612 test and bla h blah blah toc410183666."
```

I would like to remove the words starting with `toc`. The numbers behind `toc` are always different, but they are always 9 characters long.

Is there a way to do this?
I tried this:

```
$text = "Hello, my name is Lorum and toc341013697 I'm 29 years old. And I toc241053612 test and bla h blah blah toc410183666.";
$toc = substr($text, strpos($text, "toc") + strlen("toc"), 9);
$toc = "toc".$toc." ";
$find = array($toc);
$replace = array("");

$text = str_replace($find, $replace, $text);
```

But the he only removes the first toc.

Comment: try `preg_replace('/toc[0-9]{9}/','', $text);` Your way will only remove the first one if you aren't even getting an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) to replace multiple strings that are similar using a [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/):

```
$text = "Hello, my name is Lorum and toc341013697 I'm 29 years old. And I toc241053612 test and bla h blah blah toc410183666.";
$text = preg_replace('/toc[0-9]{9}/','', $text);
```

outputs:

> Hello, my name is Lorum and I'm 29 years old. And I test and bla h blah blah .

The regular expression `toc[0-9]{9}` will replace every occurence of "toc" with exactly 9 digits behind it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = "Hello, my name is Lorum and toc341013697 I'm 29 years old. And I toc241053612 test and bla h blah blah toc410183666.";

$pos = 0;
while(($pos = strpos($string, 'toc', $pos)) !== false){
    $end = $pos + 13;
    for($i = $pos; $i < $end; $i++){
            $string[$i] = '';
    }
    $pos += strlen('toc');
}

print $string; // Hello, my name is Lorum and I'm 29 years old. And I test and bla h blah blah
```

Comment: That works too :) But I prefer the answer from @putvande, because I thinks it's easier to use ;)

Comment: I agree. I ought to use `preg_replace` a little more